Understanding discriminant of composite field via representation theory
Let $L, K$ be two number fields. If $L$ and $K$ are linearly disjoint over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we know (by [Neukirch, ch.I (2.11), Proposition])
$$
d_{LK}=d_L^{[LK:L]}d_K^{[LK/K]}
$$
where $d_K$ stands for the absolute discriminant $d_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$.
But when they are not linearly disjoint,  according to a handout [link],

In more general situations where there is either "loss of field degree" (i.e., $[F: \mathbf{Q}]<[K: \mathbf{Q}]\left[K^{\prime}: \mathbf{Q}\right]$ ) or $\operatorname{gcd}\left(\operatorname{disc}(K), \operatorname{disc}\left(K^{\prime}\right)\right)>1$ this formula relating the three discriminants will fail. It is generally hopeless to expect to compute $\operatorname{disc}(F)$ just from knowledge of $\operatorname{disc}(K), \operatorname{disc}\left(K^{\prime}\right)$, and some field degrees when $\operatorname{disc}(K)$ and $\operatorname{disc}\left(K^{\prime}\right)$ share a nontrivial common factor. The explanation for why this is the case rests on a much deeper understanding of the discriminants by means of representation theory, a topic that lies way beyond the level of this course.

I feel very curious about what "a much deeper understanding of the discriminants by means of representation theory" means. Could anybody give a short explanation or simply point out a relevant reference for a deeper understanding?
Thanks in advance!

You might try emailing Brian Conrad to ask. I'm just speculating, but I wonder if it has to do with higher ramification groups, as mentioned here and here.
